# QGraphicsItem rendering on Apple Retina Display

Tags: qt, pyqt, retina-display, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I'm adding support for the Apple Retina Display to my PyQt5 application. While I successfully managed to render high resolution icons (by adding the **@2x** suffix to all my `.png` files and setting the `Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps` in my `QApplication`), I'm having some troubles in rendering high resolutions `QGraphicsItem` in a `QGraphicsScene` + `QGraphicsView`.

In my application, other than loading `.png` files, I also generate several `QPixmap` my self (embedding them into a `Icon`), to build the palette of symbols the user can use to add new shapes to the diagram rendered in the `QGraphicsView`, i.e:

```
def icon(cls, width, height, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns an icon of this item suitable for the palette.
    :type width: int
    :type height: int
    :rtype: QIcon
    """
    icon = QIcon()
    for i in (1.0, 2.0):
        # CREATE THE PIXMAP
        pixmap = QPixmap(width * i, height * i)
        pixmap.setDevicePixelRatio(i)
        pixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)
        # PAINT THE SHAPE
        polygon = cls.createPolygon(46, 34)
        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0), 1.1, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QColor(252, 252, 252))
        painter.translate(width / 2, height / 2)
        painter.drawPolygon(polygon)
        # PAINT THE TEXT INSIDE THE SHAPE
        painter.setFont(Font('Arial', 11, Font.Light))
        painter.drawText(polygon.boundingRect(), Qt.AlignCenter, 'role')
        painter.end()
        # ADD THE PIXMAP TO THE ICON
        icon.addPixmap(pixmap)
    return icon
```

Which generate one of the symbols in my Palette (the diamond one).

[image: Eddy Palette]

However when I add elements to my `QGraphicsScene`, displayed in a `QGraphicsView` they are rendered in low resolution:

```
def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
    """
    Paint the node in the diagram.
    :type painter: QPainter
    :type option: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem
    :type widget: QWidget
    """
    painter.setPen(self.pen)
    painter.setBrush(self.brush)
    painter.drawPolygon(self.polygon)
```

[image: Eddy Diagram]

The text within the shape is rendered correctly, and I'm not painting it myself since it's a `QGraphicsTextItem` having my `QGraphicsItem` as parent.

The problem is that while for `QPixmap` I can set the device pixel ratio, for `QGraphicsItem` i cannot. Am I missing something?

I'm using PyQt 5.5.1 built against Qt 5.5.1 and SIP 4.18 (not using 5.6 since I'm experiencing several crashes on application startup which I already reported to PyQt devs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not what you wanted to hear, but [Qt added retina support in 5.6](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/26/high-dpi-support-in-qt-5-6/).

Comment: I guess I missed the blog post, even though I have been looking for news regarding High DPI support in Qt 5.5/5.6. I guess I just have to wait for a fix in PyQt 5.6.

Comment: Even though your answer doesn't solve my problem (since it's not apparently solvable without upgrading to the newest version of Qt) I'll give you the bounty for the effort.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also struggling with the similar issue in PyQt 5.7.

If you are writing your sub class of QGraphicsItem, try to set render hint to antialias in the paint() method:

```
def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
    """
    Paint the node in the diagram.
    :type painter: QPainter
    :type option: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem
    :type widget: QWidget
    """
    painter.setPen(self.pen)
    painter.setBrush(self.brush)
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing) # <-- add this line
    painter.drawPolygon(self.polygon)
```

Note, this may not be the best or correct answer.